# Dúvida - Controllers Angular

Tags: angularjs

estou estudando Angular e me surgiu uma dúvida.
Estou criando uma aplicação, e queria organizar os controllers criando um para cada View (template).

```
Exemplo:
Tela Cadastro - controller-cadastro.js
Tela Login - controller-cadastro.js
Tela Vídeos - controller-videos.js
```

Posso criar um controller para cada view? Esta lógica está correta? Existe uma forma mais inteligente e usual para um controller controlar uma view diferente e manter a estrutura dos arquivos dividida?

Comment: "*Posso criar um controller para cada view?*" Pode, pode criar quantos quiser. "*Esta lógica está correta?*" Que lógica? Isso é questão de organização, faça da melhor forma pra você. "*Existe uma forma mais inteligente e usual para um controller controlar uma view diferente e manter a estrutura dos arquivos dividida?*" Não entendi essa parte.

Comment: @jbueno minha dúvida de forma resumida é, se eu conseguiria criar os controllers em arquivos separados

Comment: Pode, cara. Pode fazer como quiser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode ter um `Controller` por `view`, mas o importante é reconhecer que o conceito de `Controller` serve para separar os escopos da aplicação. O `Controller` desacopla o formato dos dados da apresentação. Por exemplo, você pode ter dados de cliente mas não querer mostrar todos eles em determinada `view`.

Aproveitando sua dúvida e notando que você está interessado na melhor forma de programar utilizando AngularJS, um bom material de boas práticas que é o [Angular Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide).

Comment: Valeu cara, saquei.
Minha dúvida era se eu poderia criar os controllers em arquivos separados, saca?

Comment: @JulioRodrigues A resposta lhe foi útil? Não esqueça de marcar o ✅ para que possa ser utilizada caso alguém tenha uma dúvida similar!

Comment: valeu man, foi sim!